# Search partial string of a Cell in Google Sheet using Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, full-text-search, google-sheets-api

I copied a scrip to search a Google Sheet but it will only return results if the search is the exact content of the cell. The cells have names. For example, row 1 have "John Doe". It will only bring results if I search for "John Doe". If I search just John or Doe or part of the name it will not return any resul.

```
    <div class="container">
        <br>
          <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ------------------------------------------------ -->
          <form id="search-form" class="form-inline" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchtext" name="searchtext" placeholder="Digite parte do nome">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Pesquisar</button>
              </form>
              <!-- ## SEARCH FORM ~ END ------------------------------------------- -->
        </div>
            <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ------------------------------------------------ -->
            <div id="search-results" class="table-responsive">
              <!-- The Data Table is inserted here by JavaScript -->
            </div>
            <!-- ## TABLE OF SEARCH RESULTS ~ END ------------------------------------------------ -->
          <br>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: PLlease post `handleFormSubmit(this)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Search for partial matches in spreadsheet

```
function search(needle="COL") {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.clearContents();
  let a = ss.createTextFinder(needle).findAll().map(r => [r.getSheet().getName(),r.getA1Notation()]);
  sh.getRange("A1:C1").setValues([["Sheet Name","A1Notation",needle]])
  sh.getRange(2,1,a.length,2).setValues(a);
}
```

My Results:

| Sheet Name | A1Notation | COL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Form Responses 7 | B1 |  |
| Form Responses 7 | C1 |  |
| Form Responses 6 | B1 |  |
| Form Responses 6 | C1 |  |
| Form Responses 6 | D1 |  |
| Form Responses 6 | F1 |  |
| Form Responses 6 | G1 |  |
| Form Responses 6 | H1 |  |
| Sheet0 | C1 |  |
| Sheet1 | A1 |  |
| Sheet1 | B1 |  |
| Sheet1 | C1 |  |
| Sheet1 | D1 |  |
| Sheet1 | E1 |  |
| Sheet1 | F1 |  |
| Sheet1 | G1 |  |
| Sheet1 | H1 |  |
| Sheet1 | I1 |  |
| Sheet1 | J1 |  |
| Sheet1 | K1 |  |
| Sheet1 | L1 |  |
| Sheet1 | M1 |  |
| Sheet1 | N1 |  |
| Sheet1 | O1 |  |
| Sheet1 | P1 |  |
| Sheet1 | Q1 |  |
| Sheet1 | R1 |  |
| Sheet1 | S1 |  |
| Sheet1 | T1 |  |
| Purchase | C13 |  |
| Current Podcasts | A2 |  |
| Current Podcasts | F15 |  |
| Current Podcasts | F17 |  |
| Current Podcasts | E23 |  |
| Current Podcasts | F23 |  |
| Current Podcasts | F24 |  |
| Current Podcasts | B28 |  |
| Current Podcasts | E28 |  |
| Current Podcasts | F28 |  |
| Current Podcasts | F35 |  |
| Current Podcasts | A37 |  |
| Current Podcasts | F37 |  |
| ProjectsFromSnippet | D6 |  |
| ProjectsFromSnippet | D171 |  |
| ProjectsFromSnippet | B215 |  |
| ProjectsFromSnippet | D215 |  |
| Listened Podcasts | B160 |  |
| Listened Podcasts | A224 |  |
| Listened Podcasts | A240 |  |
| Listened Podcasts | A241 |  |
| Listened Podcasts | A242 |  |
| Listened Podcasts | A243 |  |
| Listened Podcasts | A249 |  |
| Listened Podcasts | B253 |  |
| Listened Podcasts | A256 |  |
| Listened Podcasts | A262 |  |
| Listened Podcasts | B267 |  |
| Shared Drives | A6 |  |
| Shared Drives | A619 |  |
| Files | E75 |  |
| Files | D111 |  |
| Files | E111 |  |
| Files | D229 |  |
| Files | E229 |  |
| Files | A377 |  |
| Files | D543 |  |
| Files | E543 |  |
| Projects | D6 |  |
| Projects | D213 |  |
| Projects | B265 |  |
| Projects | D265 |  |
| Projects | E568 |  |
| Projects | C630 |  |
| Projects | C642 |  |
| Projects from Cloud Resource Manager API | E81 |  |
| Projects from Cloud Resource Manager API | E119 |  |
| Projects from Cloud Resource Manager API | E149 |  |